# Array data not working in createForm symfony

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have this form Type :

```php
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Repository\App\ArreteItemRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class ArreteItemOrderType extends AbstractType
{
    private ArreteItemRepository $arreteItemRepository;

    public function __construct(ArreteItemRepository $arreteItemRepository)
    {
        $this->arreteItemRepository = $arreteItemRepository;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('priority_vu', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => $this->arreteItemRepository->getOrderedPriority('vu', $options['demande_type']),
                'choice_label' => 'content',
                'choice_value' => 'id',
                'mapped' => false,
                'multiple' => true,
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'form-control',
                    'selected' => true
                ]
            ])
            ->add('priority_article', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => $this->arreteItemRepository->getOrderedPriority('article', $options['demande_type']),
                'choice_label' => 'content',
                'choice_value' => 'id',
                'mapped' => false,
                'multiple' => true,
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                ]
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => null
        ]);
    }
}
```

In my controller i want to inject selected value by default like this :

```php
$vues = $arreteItemRepository->getOrderedPriority('vu', $type);
$articles = $arreteItemRepository->getOrderedPriority('article', $type);
$form = $this->createForm(ArreteItemOrderType::class, [
    'priority_vu' => $vues,
    'priority_article' => $articles
], ['demande_type' => $type]); // NOT WORKING
```

This one not working, the options in select are not selected by default.

But if i write this:

```php
$vues = $arreteItemRepository->getOrderedPriority('vu', $type);
$articles = $arreteItemRepository->getOrderedPriority('article', $type);
$form = $this->createForm(ArreteItemOrderType::class, null, ['demande_type' => $type]);
$form->get('priority_vu')->setData($vues);
$form->get('priority_article')->setData($articles);
```

It's working, the options are selected by default.

Can you help me to understand this please (why with array it's not working) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by removed these lines:

```php
'mapped' => false
```